# Multiple COUNTs on multiple joins mysteriously multiplies the counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id    SMALLINT     UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    slug  VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ...
) ENGINE InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE comments (
    id    INT        UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post  SMALLINT   UNSIGNED REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    ...
) ENGINE InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE visits (
    id    INT        UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post  SMALLINT   UNSIGNED REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    ...
) ENGINE InnoDB ;
```

And this query

```
SELECT
    posts.*,
    DATE_FORMAT(posts.posted, '%W, %M %e, %Y') as d,
    COUNT(visits.post) as views,
    COUNT(comments.post) as comments
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN visits ON posts.id = visits.post
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post
WHERE
    posts.slug = '$slug'
    AND posts.published = 1
    AND posts.visible = 1 ;
```

Unfortunately, both `views` and `comments` end up containing the same value: the number of comments multiplied by the number of visits. Either one of the count/join pairs work on their own, but once I have both together, I get this result. Why is that?

I've tried adding `GROUP BY posts.id` at the end, but it makes no difference.

Since the `slug` column contains unique values, there should only be one result from this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't "mysterious".  This is how joins work.  If a post has 3 visits and 4 comments, then you will get 12 rows from your query logic before the aggregation.

In your query, you can fix this using `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT
    posts.*,
    DATE_FORMAT(posts.posted, '%W, %M %e, %Y') as d,
    COUNT(distinct visits.id) as views,
    COUNT(distinct comments.id) as comments
    . . .
```

This will work as long as you don't have hundreds of visits and comments for a given post.  In those situations, you need to pre-aggregate the results before doing the join or do the aggregation in a subquery for each post.

Comment: I see. Most likely there will be many more visits than comments. Using `distinct` just gives me a value of 1 for both, regardless of the actual counts. How would I pre-aggregate the results?

Comment: @adcoon . . . They should be counting the `id` column, not the `post` column.

Comment: Oh, right. That works. Why won't it work with hundreds of rows?

Comment: @Adcoon . . . It will work with hundreds of rows, but the intermediate results will have tens of thousands or hundreds of thousand or more rows for each post.  That affects performance.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll consider splitting it up in two, then. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can also add a `group by` clause, as I've stated in my answer. That solves both problems.

Comment: It will help.  mysql will still have to do around the same amount of *work*, but will send far less data to your application. It will allow it to utilize indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `group by post.id` clause to you're query.

A join causes a "cartesian product" to occur wherever there is a match on the "on clause". (left or right joins allow 'missing' ons to return null values instead).  Group by will tell SQL to take that cartesian product, but combine results with matching values to be confined to a single row.